# No module named 'oauth2' when using ckanext-oauth2

Tags: ckan

I'm going to use `ckan-docker` repository in my Mac to explore CKAN's functionalities. I am trying to use `ckanext-oauth2` extension to see how it would work with my own OAuth2 Provider application.

I have added the following line to the `Dockerfile.dev` of the ckan-docker repository:

`RUN pip3 install -e git+https://github.com/conwetlab/ckanext-oauth2.git#egg=ckanext-oauth2`

Now, when I run docker containers I get the following error log in the `ckan-docker-ckan-dev-1` container:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/bin/ckan", line 8, in 
> sys.exit(ckan())
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in **call**
> return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1054, in main
> with self.make_context(prog_name, args, **extra) as ctx:
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 920, in make_context
> self.parse_args(ctx, args)
> File "/srv/app/src/ckan/ckan/cli/cli.py", line 121, in parse_args
> result = super().parse_args(ctx, args)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1613, in parse_args
> rest = super().parse_args(ctx, args)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1378, in parse_args
> value, args = param.handle_parse_result(ctx, opts, args)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 2360, in handle_parse_result
> value = self.process_value(ctx, value)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 2322, in process_value
> value = self.callback(ctx, self, value)
> File "/srv/app/src/ckan/ckan/cli/cli.py", line 131, in _init_ckan_config
> _add_ctx_object(ctx, value)
> File "/srv/app/src/ckan/ckan/cli/cli.py", line 140, in _add_ctx_object
> ctx.obj = CtxObject(path)
> File "/srv/app/src/ckan/ckan/cli/cli.py", line 57, in **init**
> self.app = make_app(raw_config)
> File "/srv/app/src/ckan/ckan/config/middleware/**init**.py", line 27, in make_app
> load_environment(conf)
> File "/srv/app/src/ckan/ckan/config/environment.py", line 69, in load_environment
> p.load_all()
> File "/srv/app/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 222, in load_all
> load(*plugins)
> File "/srv/app/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 238, in load
> service = _get_service(plugin)
> File "/srv/app/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 345, in _get_service
> return plugin.load()(name=plugin_name)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2471, in load
> return self.resolve()
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2477, in resolve
> module = **import**(self.module_name, fromlist=['**name**'], level=0)
> File "/srv/app/src/ckanext-oauth2/ckanext/oauth2/plugin.py", line 24, in 
> import oauth2
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2'

I am not sure if I should change the source code of the ckanext-oauth2 or I am missing some configs.

Comment: Dockerized environments and extensions could be tricky. Maybe you could try to add some script in the entrypoints of your container to try to reinstall the extensions with `python setup.py develop`